# Add author at SFX archive with WinRAR

Tags: winrar, digital-signature, self-extracting, signature

For example:

[image]

In "Autore" i want insert an author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dialog shows *Authenticode* signature information. You'll need to:

1. buy a digital certificate (look specifically for "code signing"),
2. use `signtool` to add a signature to the .exe file, using your certificate.

Note: I'm not entirely sure if it's compatible with SFX archives. On the one hand, they're just .exe files like any other. But on the other hand, their internal structure is slightly unusual (essentially a stub with a RAR file appended), so it could be that signing may damage the archive. I'll need to research more...

Comment: [Is it possible to sign archives?](https://superuser.com/questions/426337/is-it-possible-to-sign-archives) seems to indicate you are right

Comment: I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Grawity's answer is the correct way to add an author but signing with signtool seems to corrupt an sfx archive.

I had a 4gb sfx file and after signing it with a certificate the size shrunk to 27mb and it would not extract. With the increasing security of Windows Defender SmartScreen, I don't see a way to share and use an sfx file without a tool like 7-zip.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! The site's Q&A format reserves answers for solutions to the question.  This post is really a comment rather than an answer. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).